# MacBook 15% battery drain overnight

Tags: macos, macos-catalina

So my Mac looses a lot of battery during sleep mode. I read and tried everything I found, but the problem persists. I have a MacBook Pro 2015 13" with macOS Catalina 10.15.2, Power nap = off, allow bluetooth devices to wake = off, screen time = off, do not disturb when sleeping = on. Did SMC and NVRAM reset, ran in safe mode. Nothing changed.

pmset -g log seems to show, that "com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,297" is responsible for the drain. Here is the log:

```
2020-01-27 23:15:12 +0100 Notification          Display is turned off                                                                 
2020-01-27 23:15:12 +0100 Assertions            PID 170(hidd) Summary UserIsActive "com.apple.iohideventsystem.queue.tickle serviceID:1000002e1 name:NULL product:Apple Internal Keyb eventType:11" 00:00:01  id:0x0x900008018 [System: DeclUser IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2020-01-27 23:15:12 +0100 Assertions            PID 129(powerd) Summary InternalPreventDisplaySleep "com.apple.powermanagement.delayDisplayOff" 00:00:19  id:0x0x1000008001 [System: DeclUser IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2020-01-27 23:15:12 +0100 Assertions            PID 150(apsd) Summary InteractivePushServiceTask "com.apple.apsd-lastpowerassertionlinger" 00:00:00  id:0x0x12000080c8 [System: DeclUser IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2020-01-27 23:15:12 +0100 Assertions            PID 150(apsd) Summary InteractivePushServiceTask "com.apple.apsd-datareceived-push.apple.com" 00:00:00  id:0x0x12000080c9 [System: DeclUser IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2020-01-27 23:15:12 +0100 Assertions            Kernel Idle sleep preventers: -None-          
2020-01-27 23:15:12 +0100 Assertions            [System: DeclUser IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2020-01-27 23:15:12 +0100 Assertions            PID 129(powerd) Created InternalPreventSleep "com.apple.powermanagement.darkwakelinger" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd000080ca [System: DeclUser SRPrevSleep IntPrevDisp kCPU kDisp]          
2020-01-27 23:15:12 +0100 AppWakeReason         AppWoke:com.apple.bluetoothd-blueavengers Reason:BlueAvengers: Toggle beacon state            
2020-01-27 23:15:28 +0100 Assertions            PID 129(powerd) TimedOut InternalPreventSleep "com.apple.powermanagement.darkwakelinger" 00:00:15  id:0x0xd000080ca [System: DeclUser SRPrevSleep IntPrevDisp kCPU kDisp]          
2020-01-27 23:15:28 +0100 Assertions            Summary- [System: DeclUser IntPrevDisp kDisp] Using Batt(Charge: 93)          
2020-01-27 23:15:28 +0100 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Clamshell Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=active Using Batt (Charge:93%) 835 secs  
2020-01-27 23:15:33 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=43255 wakeAt=2020-01-28 11:16:28] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=527288 wakeAt=2020-02-03 01:43:41 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,297"]           
2020-01-27 23:15:33 +0100 PM Client Acks        Delays to Sleep notifications: [com.apple.apsd is slow(2800 ms)] [mDNSResponder is slow(5027 ms)]           
2020-01-27 23:29:23 +0100 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Sleep notifications: [AppleIntelFramebuffer driver is slow(msg: SetState to 1)(1447 ms)] [powerd is slow(5033 ms)] [AppleThunderboltNHIType2 driver is slow(msg: WillChangeState to 2)(360 ms)] [RP03 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(1010 ms)]           
2020-01-27 23:29:23 +0100 Assertions            PID 233(mDNSResponder) Created MaintenanceWake "mDNSResponder:maintenance" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd000080f2 [System: PrevIdle DeclUser IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2020-01-27 23:29:23 +0100 Assertions            PID 233(mDNSResponder) Released MaintenanceWake "mDNSResponder:maintenance" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd000080f2 [System: PrevIdle DeclUser IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2020-01-27 23:29:23 +0100 Notification          Next immediate inactivity window start:'2020-01-27 23:15:00 +0100' end:'2020-01-28 10:15:00 +0100'            
2020-01-27 23:29:23 +0100 Notification          Next largest inactivity window start:'2020-01-28 23:00:00 +0100' end:'2020-01-29 10:15:00 +0100'              
2020-01-27 23:29:23 +0100 Assertions            PID 129(powerd) Created InternalPreventSleep "Network wake delay proxy assertion" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd000080f3 [System: DeclUser IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2020-01-27 23:29:23 +0100 DarkWake              DarkWake from Deep Idle [CDN] : due to ARPT/Network Using BATT (Charge:92%) 30 secs   
2020-01-27 23:29:23 +0100 WakeDetails           DriverReason:ARPT - DriverDetails:                                         
2020-01-27 23:29:23 +0100 HibernateStats        hibmode=3 standbydelaylow=10800 standbydelayhigh=86400                                799           
2020-01-27 23:29:23 +0100 WakeTime              WakeTime: 0.840 sec                                                                   
2020-01-27 23:29:23 +0100 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: [AirPort_BrcmNIC driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(520 ms)]           
2020-01-27 23:29:53 +0100 Assertions            PID 129(powerd) TimedOut InternalPreventSleep "Network wake delay proxy assertion" 00:00:30  id:0x0xd000080f3 [System: DeclUser SRPrevSleep IntPrevDisp kCPU kDisp]          
2020-01-27 23:29:53 +0100 Sleep                 Entering Sleep state due to 'Maintenance Sleep':TCPKeepAlive=inactive Using Batt (Charge:92%) 30776 secs
2020-01-27 23:29:55 +0100 Wake Requests         [*process=powerd request=TCPKATurnOff deltaSecs=42392 wakeAt=2020-01-28 11:16:28] [process=powerd request=UserWake deltaSecs=526425 wakeAt=2020-02-03 01:43:41 info="com.apple.alarm.user-visible-Weekly Usage Report,297"]           
2020-01-27 23:29:55 +0100 PM Client Acks        Delays to Sleep notifications: [com.apple.apsd is slow(1782 ms)]           
2020-01-28 08:02:49 +0100 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Sleep notifications: [AppleThunderboltNHIType2 driver is slow(msg: WillChangeState to 2)(363 ms)] [RP03 driver is slow(msg: SetState to 0)(1105 ms)]           
2020-01-28 08:02:49 +0100 Notification          Display is turned on                                                                  
2020-01-28 08:02:49 +0100 Assertions            Kernel Idle sleep preventers: IODisplayWrangler          
2020-01-28 08:02:49 +0100 Assertions            PID 233(mDNSResponder) Created MaintenanceWake "mDNSResponder:maintenance" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd0000810a [System: PrevIdle DeclUser IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2020-01-28 08:02:49 +0100 Assertions            PID 233(mDNSResponder) Released MaintenanceWake "mDNSResponder:maintenance" 00:00:00  id:0x0xd0000810a [System: PrevIdle DeclUser IntPrevDisp kDisp]          
2020-01-28 08:02:49 +0100 Wake                  Wake from Deep Idle [CDNVA] : due to EC.LidOpen/Lid Open Using BATT (Charge:77%)           
2020-01-28 08:02:49 +0100 WakeDetails           DriverReason:WiFi.ScanOffload - DriverDetails:                             
2020-01-28 08:02:49 +0100 HibernateStats        hibmode=3 standbydelaylow=10800 standbydelayhigh=86400                                800           
2020-01-28 08:02:49 +0100 WakeTime              WakeTime: 0.907 sec                                                                   
2020-01-28 08:02:49 +0100 Kernel Client Acks    Delays to Wake notifications: [AppleIntelFramebuffer driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(444 ms)] [AirPort_BrcmNIC driver is slow(msg: SetState to 2)(479 ms)]
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thank you very much in advance!

Edit: 
Battery condition according to macOS battery information: good (145 cycles), according to Coconut Battery: 95,1%

Answer (score 3):

I spent hours on the same problem, I even did a clean install of my Macbook. This is the solution I ended up with. Actually it's not technically a solution, but a workaround.
Change hibernation mode to 25, which means full hibernation, aka not powering RAM. to do that, use the following command from terminal app:

```
pmset -b hibernatemode 25
```

Downside of this is slower wake up, but since SSDs are pretty fast these days, it's not that big a problem anymore.

Another thing I've tried, which you might want to try too is `sleepwatcher`. It's an app that can monitor the machine going to sleep and waking up and let you run scripts/take actions etc. What I used to do was I would run a script to turn off WIFI when the machine goes to sleep. I don't remember exactly how much it improved the situation though. I've been using Windows almost exclusively lately because of work. To install `sleepwatch`, you can use brew:

```
brew install sleepwatcher
```

Then read the documents that come with it on how to use.

One more thing you can try is you can wipe the machine and do a clean install. Again I don't remember how much effect it had on battery drain, sorry.
Those 2 methods were the most effective ones I tried as long as I remember. they should at least have some effect, probably pretty good effect.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, David! Does Find my Mac still work with full hibernation?

Comment: I don’t know honesty. I was actually suspecting if that kind of thing was the source of the battery drain and tried to turn it off.

Comment: Hmm. I haf the same thought and have it turned off also, but I‘d like to use it actually... Does someone know more?